# Configure netplan to use a different interface for bridge

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virsh, netplan

I'm setting up a virtual machine host on Ubuntu 18.04.3. I installed KVM and have succesfully set up a qemu vm which connects through a bridged network. It shows up as a regular machine in my network.

vm host: 192.168.178.14
vm guest: 192.168.178.15

So I got bridging working fine with netplan. That was on a test machine with a test vm. Now on my production server I added a second network card containing four network interfaces.

The host's 'own' network interface is enp7s0.
The extra network interfaces are called enp4s0f0, enp4s0f1, enp5s0f0 and enp5s0f1. I connected enp5s0f1 and what I am trying to do is bridge enp5s0f1 for use with a vm.

/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml looks like this:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.178.14/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.178.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.178.1]

    enp5s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
  version: 2

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp5s0f1]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.178.17/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.178.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.178.1]
```

I did not forget to do netplan apply. No error there.

I installed the vm, which went just fine. It installed from an internet repository so I am certain it has network connectivity. I installed openssh-server, just like in my testing environment.

However, when I tried to connect via ssh to the new vm, it didn't work. (The host runs ssh on a non-standard port instead of 22; the guest runs ssh on port 22.)

If I look in my client's arp table I find that 192.168.178.17 has the same mac address as 192.168.178.14. So it looks like the bridging isn't working.

Not sure if it is necessary, but also created an xml file

```
 <network>
  <name>host-bridge</name>
  <uuid>d90796c6-f38f-42cd-ad55-6f95a8feebe6</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='br0'/>
</network>
```

Imported it and now it shows up at virsh net-list -all:

```
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes
 host-bridge          active     yes           yes
```

No joy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A virtual network representing the host bridge is not necessary. How did you configure networking in the VM?

Comment: Found the problem: setup was messed up. Started from scratch and it just worked. @MichaelHampton, what exactly do you mean by 'A virtual network representing the host bridge is not necessary'? Do you mean the virtlib xml bridge definition of the bridge definition in the netplan yaml file?